# Encrypt URL Query Parameters in OFBiz Framework

Tags: security, ofbiz

I am developing ofbiz projects and I need to encrypt the url query parameter. I searched in google but can`t able to get any idea. Please help me to find the solution.

In url.properties file

### service.http.parameters.require.encrypted=Y

I am using https request and don`t know what is the configuration settings for the https request.

Thanks in advance.